# Can Methylene Blue Detect Spoilage in Food?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox, aqueous-solution, solutions

Initially, there is already a product which is a sensor based on Methylene Blue, which can detect changes in oxygen levels in a packaging. However, as our thesis project, we decided to take on this and make it more simple and replicable.

So this is our concern. We decided to try and replicate the "blue bottle experiment", which is Glucose and Sodium hydroxide mixed to form an alkaline solution and then Methylene Blue will be added. At first it will be blue, but once it settles, it will turn clear. When the solution is shaken, it will turn blue again, and then turn clear once again when settled.

In theory, if a strip of filter paper was dipped into this "blue-bottle" solution, will it turn blue once it detects high levels of oxygen? (This is provided that the filter paper will remain moist)

ps. the reason why i'm asking for professional opinions and answers is that we cannot afford to buy expensive materials if we don't know if it will work in the first place.

Comment: This is an excellent idea. And you could keep these paper strips in small closed plastic bags. What should be known is the sensitivity of the test, which I don't know.

Comment: The test is *incredibly* sensitive to oxygen as normally performed. It seems you have two tasks: reducing sensitivity, and keeping the test paper moist without touching the food. Good luck with your experiments, and please report back here with your own answer.